# conditionally use default Histogram bounds

Tags: r

I'd like to make a histogram determine its bounds in the default way, or as specified by an existing variable depending on a boolean. The problem is these default values: `hist(breaks="Sturges",xlim=range(breaks))` so I can't just `hist(data,xlim=ifelse(myBool,range(breaks),myBounds))` like I'd like to do, since it'll return a 'object "breaks" not found' error...

As a workaround I could find the default bounds myself, does anyone know what formula they use for this?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what "this" refers to in your last sentence, but you can look at `hist.default`, and see that it calls `nclass.Sturges` to get the the number of bins.

Comment: why won't this work? `hist(mtcars$mpg, xlim = if (TRUE) c(0, 40) else range(hist(mtcars$mpg)$breaks))`

Comment: gregor, I don't need the number of bins, I need the bounds
rawr, you're generating the histogram twice

Comment: I meant to have plot = FALSE in that so it *wont* be generated twice `hist(mtcars$mpg, xlim = if (TRUE) c(0, 40) else range(hist(mtcars$mpg, plot = FALSE)$breaks))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just two calls based on your indicator:

```
if(myBool) {
    hist(data)
} else {
    hist(data, xlim = myBounds)
}
```

Looking at the code for `hist.default`, when `breaks = "Sturges"` the breaks are calculated as

```
breaks = pretty(range(x), n = nclass.Sturges(x), min.n = 1)
```

So you could set:

```
hist(data,
     xlim = if(myBool) {range(pretty(range(data), n = nclass.Sturges(data), min.n = 1))} else {myBounds})
```

(`ifelse` wont work here because your condition `myBool` is of length one and you need to return a vector of length 2.) Or as @rawr suggests:

```
hist(data,
     xlim = ifelse(c(myBool, myBool),
                   range(pretty(range(data), n = nclass.Sturges(data), min.n = 1)),
                   myBounds))
```

Comment: I'll wait on the accept if someone has a cleaner way with one hist() but yeah, this is a better workaround

Comment: I'd be surprised if someone works more on this, e.g., calculating the breaks, unless you make your question reproducible. Can you give a more concrete example of what you're trying to do with, e.g., the `mtcars` dataset?

Comment: I'm not sure you can be a lot cleaner here. The original problem is that the default `xlim=` value is based on the `breaks` variable which is not external to the function. Just running `hist(..., xlim=range(breaks))` will not work because variables passed to a function are evaluated in the calling context while variables set as default parameters are evaluated in the function enclosure. You could use `do.call` to modify a call to `hist()` if there many other parmeters you want to set, but you'll still need a hard `if()` block in there somewhere to only conditionally replace the parameter.

Comment: My actual use of this will get pretty messy since it uses shiny, and I think that's way more info than this question needs. I know Gregor, I wouldn't expect anyone to work more, so in all likelihood I'll end up accepting your answer, since it does work. I just try not to accept answers too quickly on SO as it discourages others who may want to work on better solutions.

Comment: Also I still would be interested in what formula they use. For the y axis its just 1.04*max so I thought there might be some similarly simple formula (that wouldn't require a reproducible example to answer)

Comment: I'm not trying to get you to accept my answer, but as-is your question is abstract enough to be difficult to understand. From your edits, apparently I misinterpreted which case was which. A concrete example, even an overly-simple one, would go a long way to clearing it up.

Comment: my original state of my boolean was totally arbitrary, but when I saw that yours took it to the opposite state I figured I'd just move it around to be consistent. I could have modified my own question to fit your answer... again just an arbitrary choice. I thought it was fine to have abstract questions on here, though I did try to make it unambiguous.

Comment: It's just difficult to give a concrete answer to an abstract question. If you could show sample input and desired output, there's no guesswork as to whether an answer works or not.

Comment: I'd argue that you can have a pseudocode answer to a pseudocode question. Regardless, I'll add some sample input on Monday, but I'm out now

Comment: you could still use ifelse `ifelse(c(myBool, myBool), c(0,0), c(1,1))` etc